# How to place sticky element over element to which it sticks?

Tags: html, css

When a user hovers over a given target element on my page (in this case a `p`), I would like several buttons to appear. I would like the buttons to be positioned e.g. 50px from the bottom of the target element *or* the bottom of the viewport, whichever is higher. For example, if the user hovers over the element while it is fully visible, I want the button (the greenish circle) to appear [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awz4k.png)

However, if the user scrolls up, I do not want the button to disappear offscreen, so I want the button to instead be 50px from the bottom of the viewport, [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXIVj.png)

**What I have tried so far:**

To me, this seems like a case for which `position: sticky` was designed, so I have been trying to use that. My first attempt was like this:

```css
.large {
    display: block;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6ff;
}

.target {
    background-color: #b3b3b3ff;
}

.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #008080ff;
}
```

```html
<p class="large">Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
<p class="large target">...sit amet consectetur...</p>
<div class="sticky"></div>
<p class="large">...adipiscing elit.</p>
```

However, I am encountering a problem: if I make the button `sticky`, normal flow causes it to be placed fully underneath the target element [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTQsG.png) I don't want it to be beneath the target element; I want it to be within the box of the target element [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYCRY.png)

I tried to overcome this by using a structure something like this:

```css
.large {
    display: block;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6ff;
}

.target {
    background-color: #b3b3b3ff;
}

.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #008080ff;
}

.overlay {
    /* trying to make div.overlay exactly coterminous with div.container... */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<p class="large">Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
<!-- hoping that div.container will be sized to tightly contain p "...sit amet consectetur..." -->
<div class="container">
    <p class="large target">...sit amet consectetur...</p>
    <div class="overlay">
        <!-- placing sticky in the overlay in the hopes that it will go on top of p "...sit amet consectetur..." -->
        <div class="sticky"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<p class="large">...adipiscing elit.</p>
```

... in the hopes that the outermost `div` would scale to contain the `p`, the `div` whose class is `overlay` would take on exactly the same size as the outermost `div` and allow the button to sit on top, but in doing so I discovered that putting a sticky element inside an `absolute`ly-positioned element doesn't work.

**UPDATE: Here is a snippet with the exact behavior that I want. I have used JavaScript extensively to make it work. I am hoping for a pure CSS solution, if one exists.**

```js
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        var mouseX;
        var mouseY;
        
        $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
            mouseX = event.pageX;
            mouseY = event.pageY - document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        });
        
        function mouseInRect(rect) {
            return (
                rect.x <= mouseX
             && mouseX <= rect.x + rect.width
             && rect.y <= mouseY
             && mouseY <= rect.y + rect.height );
        }
        
        function showButton(toggle) {
            if (toggle) {
                $("#button").css("display", "block");
            } else {
                $("#button").css("display", "none");
            }
        }
    
        $("#target").mouseenter(function() {
            showButton(true);
        });
        
        $("#target").mouseleave(function() {
            showButton(false);
        });
    
        $(document).scroll(function() {
            var viewportHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            var targetRect = $("#target")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
            var targetBottom = viewportHeight - targetRect.bottom;
            
            /* the button element should appear either 20 pixels from the bottom
               of the target element OR the bottom of the viewport, whichever is
               higher. */
            $("#button").css("bottom", Math.max(targetBottom + 20, 20));
            
            /* the user scrolling can cause the mouse pointer to leave the
               target element without generating a mouse leave event, so also
               compute anew whether hover is occuring inside our scroll
               handler. */
            showButton(mouseInRect(targetRect));
        });
    }
);
```

```css
.large {
    display: block;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6ff;
}

.target {
    background-color: #b3b3b3ff;
}

.sticky {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    background-color: #008080ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="large">Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
<p id="target" class="large target">...sit amet consectetur...</p>
<div id="button" class="sticky"></div>
<p class="large">...adipiscing elit.</p>
```

Comment: the code seems simple, so you better post it all here in a snippet, so we can edit it to help.

Comment: Added running code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused. so

1- when your page loads, there is no green button.

2- when hover on target, green button appear on the lower left corner of target.

do you want it to stay visible? or only when hover?

3- when user scroll down, element appear and stick on the lower left corner of view port.

is this what you want?

Anyway, I did the first step for that, and after you provide clear info, I will update or someone else will.

so to make it appear on hover,

1- put it and `target` in a `container` and set its `position` to `relative`.

2- set `sticky` position to `absolute` and display none.

3- set `target hover + sticky` to display sticky `on hover`.

```css
.large {
    display: block;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6ff;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
}

.target:hover + .sticky {
    display: block;
}


.target {

    background-color: #b3b3b3ff;
}

.sticky {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 2%;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #008080ff;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<p class="large">Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="large target">...sit amet consectetur...</p>
    <div class="sticky"></div>
</div>
  <p class="large">...adipiscing elit.</p>
```

Comment: To answer your questions: (1) yes, no button on page load, (2) that's correct, (3) actually when the user scrolls up--basically, if the bottom half of "target" is below the bottom of the viewport, *if* the user is still hovering over target, I want the button to be visible at the bottom left of the viewport (still within the target).

Comment: Well, that's good. I answered 2/3 of your question, so don't forget to upvote . And about the third point, I don't think it can be done with only CSS. We need some Javascript to do that.

Comment: Please see my edit: I have added another running snippet at the end which implements exactly the behavior I am looking for. However, the snippet uses JavaScript to implement a lot of the behavior and I would prefer a pure-HTML/CSS solution if one is possible. Lmk if you think one is possible or not.

Comment: yeah, that's what I said in my comment, we may need some js code. also, if it shows only on hover, then why do you care about scroll? it doesn't make sense.